# Возникли проблемы при попытки создания виртуальной среды для Django

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

Возникли проблемы при попытки создания виртуальной среды для Django
[image]

Comment: Не используйте картинки. Вставляйте текст. Во-вторых, какой у вас вопрос? Сообщение об ошибке явно говорит в чем проблема. Если у вас какой-то вопрос касательно этого, его нужно задать и объяснить, что непонянто.

Comment: @RomanKonoval очевидно, что автору непонятно, почему это вдруг virtualenv не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом

Comment: Создать окружение можно командой `python -m venv my_venv_name` активировать его `my_venv_name\Scripts\activate`. Далее в нем уже устанавливаете django. Если не ошибаюсь то с python3.5 virtualenv добавлен по умолчанию как venv. Некоторые отличия есть но не думаю что они сейчас важны.

Comment: @Kers, Спасибо, заработало!
Оформите свой комментарий в виде ответа, чтобы я мог его принять

Comment: @НиколайСеменов рад что помогло )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте создать виртуальное окружение командой:

```bsh
python -m venv venv_name
```

Активировать его:

```bsh
venv_name\Scripts\activate
```

Далее подключившись к окружения можно установить django.
Если не ошибаюсь то с python3.5 многие функции virtualenv добавлены по умолчанию как venv.